# How to make a KEYPAD of android to be capitalized at all time?

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

Hereby I tried to make a virtual keypad of android device to be capitalized eventhough we manually set to lowercase. For this I have tried in many ways.

In my xml:

```
android:digits="0123456789*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text|textCapCharacters"
```

but when I launch this respective activity,keypad is in **UPPERCASE** but while I manually change the case it comes to **LOWERCASE**. I need to avoid the case changes from **UPPERCASE TO LOWERCASE.**

Your answer is more appreciated!!!

**This issue would be fixed by hiding UPARROW for changing case. I m trying to do this.**

Comment: keep a text watcher to monitor and alert user

Comment: Do you want to make the input characters to upper case irrespective of the keyboard type?

Comment: Use `TextWatcher` to change characters..

Comment: No @SripadRaj . I have made this to be entered as UPPERCASE  eventhough the keypad is in lowercase.

Comment: Then I believe you should use an open source keyboard and customize according to your needs.

Comment: editText.getText().toString().toUpperCase(); will help every time i guess

Comment: My issue would be fixed by hiding UPARROW for changing case. I m trying to do this. @SripadRaj

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492284/android-capitalize-characters-not-working-in-phone

Answer (score 4):

you can use this of you edittext `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` like this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

or try this

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. It works like a charm.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

Now in your Activity do this.

```
EditText edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
edtText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this "textCapCharacters" input type

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_capitalcase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: As he specified in question he wants to prevent the action of manually changing input to lowercase by pressing shift key. This approach doesn't solve that.

Comment: But after changing the case as something will be  written it will automatically changed to uppercase. So i produce this solution. @MohammedJunaid

Comment: The first character entered after manually changing to lower case is entered as lowercase before the keyboard changes itself to uppercase. To prevent this InputFilter is used. @Ankita