# Android EditText upper case alphanumeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText and it should display alphanumeric keyboard (both letters and numbers visible on keyboard). Letters must be upper case. What attributes should I set for EditText? I tried:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

This shows lower case alphanumeric keyboard.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

And this shows upper case keyboard but without numbers.

I need a keyboard like this:
[image]

Both numbers and upper case letters visible on default layout (without the need to switch CAPS on, or in other words with CAPS turned on in default).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Capitalize characters not working in phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492284/android-capitalize-characters-not-working-in-phone)

Comment: After time we have spent to answer your question, you have changed your question. You should describe your question better at first. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492284/android-capitalize-characters-not-working-in-phone

Comment: I asked: "it should display alphanumeric keyboard (both letters and numbers visible on keyboard)" I think it is clear...

Comment: Now it is clear, after we spent time for answering you

Comment: You can change keyboard style in settings of your phone. User can also set keyboard so that it is invisible at all. But you can make custom keyboard. This question may help you: How can you make a custom keyboard in Android?

Answer (score 0):

try inputType = textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work, it shows lower case alphanumeric keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`, you will have alphanumeric keyboard as you see in these pictures:

[image]
[image]

You can change keyboard style in settings of your phone. User can also set keyboard so that it is invisible at all. But you can make custom keyboard. This question may help you: [How can you make a custom keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/)

Comment: That is not what I need. I need a keyboard with upper case letters and numbers visible on one keyboard.

Comment: This way you will have alphanumeric and some other characters like ' : , ? !, if you want to have custom keyboard, it is another question.@Martin Dusek

Comment: I can see that lower case keyboard with numbers visible on the same keyboard exists. I can also see that we can switch this keyboard to upper case letters by toggling up arrow on the keyboard. So I assume there must be a way we can show upper case keyboard with numbers (without the need to toggle up arrow on the keyboard). Or do I really need custom keyboard to have upper case letters and numbers visible on keyboard? User of my app has to enter this code "F5GN2" and I want to make things as easy for user as possible. So I want to show upper case keyboard with numbers.

Comment: I think my answer is correct for this question, I recommend you to ask another quedtion "How can we make custom keyboard"?@Martin Dusek

Comment: Sorry, you probably didn't understand what I need. I modified my initial post. If you think that the right answer is "make your custom keyboard" then please modify your answer and write there "make your custom keyboard". We will see if that is the correct answer.

Comment: You can see this question to make custom keyboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/ @Martin Dusek

Answer (score 0):

You can android:digits property to restrict other text

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
```

Comment: it will allow the only Capletter and digits and space. what else you want?

Comment: Try that. You will see